# How to know when compositionComplete is done?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have:

```
compositionComplete() {
   super.compositionComplete();
   ....
}
```

but I need to run some code after *compositionComplete* is completed.
Not inside this callback.

How can I know that ?

Comment: is this related to ace code editor or something else , there is no compositionComplete  in https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace

Comment: `compositionComplete` is the Durandal event. I need to collapse the ace-editor lines after the compositionComplete.

Comment: then i think you need to remove the ace-editor tag, because your question is not related to it.

Comment: removed the ace-editor tag